# in MA-ABE, what is the diference when prove a scheme is selective or static?

Tags: encryption, public-key, abe, proof

I have read
[1]*Decentralized Multi-authority ABE for NC1 from BDH*,
[2]*Decentralizing Attribute-Based Encryption*,
[3]*Fully Adaptive Decentralized Multi-Authority ABE*,
When I compare security proof in [3](full adaptive), I find out that when construct hybrid games, authors do not rely on public and private keys generated by authorities. It makes sense because an adversary can obtain the authoriy keys at any time. However, when I compare security proof in 1 and 2,  it change the response of key queries. The adversary can query attribute keys in two phases. Why can't the adversary detect changes.

In brief, when I prove a scheme is static or adaptive, what are the restrictions? For example, when I prove a scheme is full adaptive, I can't change how the key pair is generated in hybrid games.